# Can we not use socket and threading together to send and receive messages?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to make a program to interact between client and server using socket and thread. In my
program the server is waiting for data and the client sends a data.

But after i used thread so that the data can be asked continuously it gave an error when data is being send or received.

Server

```
import socket
import threading
import keyboard

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

def receive_function(pon):
        while True:
            det = pon.recv(1024)
            if det:
                print(f"\t\t\t\tFriend: {det.decode('utf-8')}")
            else:
                continue

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST,PORT))
    s.listen()
    print("LisTenING...")
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection Established with {addr} Device")
        x = threading.Thread(target=receive_function, args=(conn,))
        x.start()
```

Client

```
import socket
import keyboard
import threading
from time import sleep

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

def send_data(s1):
        print("S1 is ",s1)
        s1.send(bytes("oi k xa", 'utf-8'))

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    x = threading.Thread(target=send_data, args=(s,))
    x.start()
```

Error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python371\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\Python371\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "practice2.py", line 11, in send_data
    s1.send(bytes("oi k xa", 'utf-8'))
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Can anyone give me solution and reason that why i am not able to send and receive data when threading is used.

Answer (score 2):

The `with` in the main thread is closing the socket when the `with` block exits.  Instead, open the socket in the thread, or move the `with` to the thread so it closes after sending.

Option 1:

```py
import socket
import threading

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

def send_data():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    with s:
        print("s is", s)
        s.sendall(b"oi k xa")

x = threading.Thread(target=send_data)
x.start()
```

Option 2:

```py
import socket
import threading

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

def send_data(s):
    with s:
        print("S1 is ",s)
        s.sendall(b"oi k xa")

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
x = threading.Thread(target=send_data, args=(s,))
x.start()
```

Comment: While valid, option 2 allows sharing socket between threads, which can be very messy without proper synchronization.